# UE4 Физика вращения двери с помощью мыши

Tags: unreal-engine-4, blueprint

У меня есть blueprint двери, которая должна вращаться по оси YAW при зажатии ЛКМ и движении мышью в нужную сторону, и она это делает. **Проблема в том, что дверь проходит сквозь другие объекты, а должна физически упираться в них.** При попытках настройки физики у объекта столкнулся с тем, что при слабом импульсе всё более менее, дверь упирается в стены, косяки и тд, но при сильном импульсе дверь пролетает через них насквозь, чего не должно быть. Пробовал ограничивать углы поворота двери, но там всё сложно, так как поворот имеет разные значения в local и в world, что блокирует поворот всегда по-разному, в зависимости от того, как дверь стоит на локации.

**Моя схема реализации двери:**

Вся основная логика находится в character'е. Через LineTracing я получаю дверь и при условии, что я двигаю с зажатой ЛКМ происходит смена параметра rotation у двери в зависимости от той стороны, куда двигаю (- и +).

**Настройки физики двери**

[image: Настройки физики двери]

**Вот что происходит, когда я вращаю дверь**

[image: Макрос вращения двери]

**Для лучшего понимания. Дверь проходит через правую стену, а должна в неё врезаться как физический объект**
[image: Дверь]

**Резюмируя. Дверь при вращении проходит сквозь объекты, хотя не должна. Что можно сделать, чтобы это исправить?**

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант решения данной проблемы:

Было решено пойти путём костыля. Я создал Box Collision в объекте двери при соприкосновением с которым дверь не могла двигаться дальше и получала небольшой импульс в обратном направлении, чтобы не застрять.

Возможно, кому-то поможет)